# Jira: a convenient report for release

Tags: report, jira

I have a set of Epics, Stories, Tasks which share same release. I want to make some reports on this. Best thing is to make Gantt chart, but as far as I understand there is no free option for that.

Next thing is just to get report on current status. I would like to see all Jiras with there status splitted by Epics and Stories, may be with blockers mentioned if any.

The only way to check all issues for release I know is to run issue search, but this produces unstructured output.

Is there any other way to create release report?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

You can Create release report using portoflio plugin for JIRA.

Here are guides how to create release report with this plugin:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiraportfoliocloud/using-the-releases-report-828785336.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiraportfolioserver/releases-report-816527567.html

You can try it for free.